# How to pass pipeline parameters to azure add using airflow

Tags: airflow, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass run parameters to an azure data factory pipeline when triggered manually with config in Apache airflow. I have set up the ability to update params as part of the run with config but I am having trouble when I try and pass them to the specific location in pipeline_parameters.

From my understanding the params should become a sort of dictionary inside of args. So I am trying to assign the values into the pipeline_parameters

I will add an abbreviated version of my code below that I have tried

```
import configparser
import sys
import pendulum

from os import path
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import DAG, Dataset

from custom_interfaces.alerts import send_alert
from custom_interfaces.models.message import MessageSettings
from custom_interfaces import AzureDataFactoryOperator

args = {
    "owner": "user-team-hr-001",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1, tzinfo=local_tz),
    "on_failure_callback": on_failure_callback,
    "retries": 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
    'params': {
        "p_date_overwrite":"",
        "p_foldername":"",
        "p_foler_prefix":""
    }
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    description="Run with Pipeline Parameters.",
    catchup=False,
    default_args = args,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
    is_paused_upon_creation=True
  
) as dag:

    run_pipeline_workday_bpt_historic_load = AzureDataFactoryOperator(
        task_id="test_load",
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        adf_sp_connection_id=config['adf_sp_connection_id'],
        subscription_id=config['subscriptions']['id'],
        resource_group_name=config['adf_resource_group'],
        factory_name=config['adf_name'],
        pipeline_name=config['adf_pipeline_name'],
        pipeline_parameters={
            "p_date_overwrite":args['params']['p_date_overwrite'],
            "p_foldername":args['params']['p_foldername'],
            "p_foler_prefix":args['params']['p_foler_prefix']
        },
        polling_period_seconds=10,
        outlets=[dataset_name]
    )
```